# Placing a d3 graph in div blocks the links above it

Tags: javascript, html, css, d3.js, svg

I'm trying to put a d3 graph in the background of a div, with copy and links above it. **The svg is a simple area graph (no frill) that deactivates/blocks the links.** I've tried tweaking the z-index with no luck. Everything works after removing the svg ..

```
<div class="card">
    <div class="card-bg"><svg/></div>
    <div class="card-top">
      <div>
        <div class="card-header">{{circle.name }}</div>
        <div class="card-subheader">Last updated {{circle.dateCreated}</div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="card-body">
        <a href="#" onclick=""><span>Link one</span></a>
        <a href="#" onclick=""><span>Link two</span></a>
        <a href="#" onclick=""><span>Link three</span></a>
        <a href="#" onclick=""><span>Link four</span></a>
        <a href="#" onclick=""><span>Link five</span></a>
    </div>
</div>
```

Style:

```
.card {
  background-color: white;
  width: 100%;
  height: 300px;
  padding: 20px;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
  border-radius: 2px;
  /* offset-x | offset-y | blur-radius | color */
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 2px rgba(33,33,33,.05);
  box-shadow: 0px 1px 2px rgba(33,33,33,.2);
  cursor: default;
  z-index:1;
  position: relative;
}

.card-bg {
  background-color: transparent;
  width: 100%;
  height: 300px;
  padding: 20px;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
  border-radius: 2px;
  z-index:0;
  position: absolute;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Define a position other than static for your `.card-body` div. For example:

```
.card-body {
    z-index: 1;
    position: relative;
}
```

Here a snippet:

```css
.card {
  background-color: white;
  width: 100%;
  height: 300px;
  padding: 20px;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
  border-radius: 2px;
  /* offset-x | offset-y | blur-radius | color */
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 2px rgba(33,33,33,.05);
  box-shadow: 0px 1px 2px rgba(33,33,33,.2);
  cursor: default;
  z-index:1;
  position: relative;
}

.card-bg {
  background-color: transparent;
  width: 100%;
  height: 300px;
  padding: 20px;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
  border-radius: 2px;
  z-index:0;
  position: absolute;
}
.card-body {
    z-index: 1;
    position: relative;
}
```

```html
<div class="card">
    <div class="card-bg"><svg/></div>
    <div class="card-top">
      <div>
        <div class="card-header">{{circle.name }}</div>
        <div class="card-subheader">Last updated {{circle.dateCreated}}</div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="card-body">
        <a href="#" onclick=""><span>Link one</span></a>
        <a href="#" onclick=""><span>Link two</span></a>
        <a href="#" onclick=""><span>Link three</span></a>
        <a href="#" onclick=""><span>Link four</span></a>
        <a href="#" onclick=""><span>Link five</span></a>
    </div>
  </div>
```